# How do I configure routes in OpenVPN?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, routing, openvpn

I dial my internet connection(PPoE) and this poses to be a problem when OpenVPN sets up routes(I think).

OpenVPN fails to route my connection with the following error message.

```
Mon Aug 06 19:31:53 2012 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Mon Aug 06 19:31:53 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.5
Mon Aug 06 19:31:53 2012 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: One or more arguments are not correct.   [status=160 if_index=29]
Mon Aug 06 19:31:53 2012 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
Mon Aug 06 19:31:53 2012 Route addition fallback to route.exe
OK!
Mon Aug 06 19:31:53 2012 Initialization Sequence Completed
Mon Aug 06 19:49:59 2012 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

Comment: when i googled about your error i found this link http://forums.openvpn.net/topic9971.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/97) in OpenVPN, the next version fixed it.